# Apply Two Animations to the Same View?

Tags: android, view, imagebutton, android-animation

I applied an entry animation to one of my ImageButton `(fade_in.xml which is in the project anim/ folder)`. Now, after a button click, I want to apply an exit animation `(fade_out.xml which is in the same folder)`

When I do that, the `entry` animation happens. However, the `exit` one do NOT !! It seems that *each View will accept ONLY one animation.*

**Is this true?** How can I work around this problem?

-

-

**UPDATE:**

This is in the `onCreate()` method for setting the entry animation:

```
Animation fade = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_in);
fade.setStartOffset(600);
img.startAnimation(fade);
img.setvisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

And this is in the `onClick()` method for some button b1:

```
Animation fade2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_out);
fade.setStartOffset(500);
img.startAnimation(fade2);
img.setvisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ViewFlipper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html) with getInAnimation and getOutAnimation methods.
Other solution is setting animation in your code(as far I understand you set animation in xml file).

Comment: This is work around. I was using two animations for one view and it was working. The only difference was that I was changing Animation in code, not in xml. I have never used animations as you say but one thing is strange for me. You want to use animation on entry and exit but the view is still there - button cannot exit when activity is there. Maybe enter and exit should be used only for activity entries(http://iserveandroid.blogspot.com/2010/11/how-to-apply-animations-when-activity.html)?

Comment: My entry and exit are for ImageView, not an Activity

Comment: That's the point. Then do you think your ImageView exits? Activity can exit, ImageView can be clicked.

Comment: Can you provide your code where you set show/entry hide/exit animation?

Comment: We should start from this point! Your problem is this line: img.setvisibility(View.INVISIBLE); Your animation can't be seen because your image is already invisible. To make it work set event listener to your animation: exitAnimation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener(){...} and override OnAnimationEnd method - just put there: img.setvisibility(View.INVISIBLE);